# Telnet scripting server

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, automation, telnet

I know this is old question, but I cant find anything on google. Is there any good software for centrally scripting telnet and ssh? Basically the following components: Telnet/SSH client, GUI, Server & Switch detection and support, pre-defined script templates, error reporting, logging, authenticating, and it's universal and not product specific.
ps. It's not product discussion, but a tool / solution question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, **Expect** is the answer. You can even see some telnet and ssh examples on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Here is for example a simple Expect script that prints the environment variables on a remote server:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet 127.0.0.1

# Send username
expect -nocase "login:"
send  "myuser\r"

# Send password
expect -nocase "password: "
send "123456\r"

# Wait for a shell prompt
expect -re {\$}

# Get the environment variables
send "env\r"

# Wait for a prompt again and exit
expect -re {\$}
exit
```

Comment: Many thanks, so I do server-side expect CGI, and the desktop/mobile client, so I can click buttons, this should be OK so I can run two clients no problem in two different rooms.